# Is it possible to create a JSON array inside a JSON object in search definition and all fields are searchable in vespa.ai?

Tags: vespa

I need to create a search definition file in Vespa where I can a JSON array inside JSON object with all fields searchable

for example-

```
{
  "department": "education",
  "designation": "student",
  "person": {
    "name": "steve",
    "city": "delhi",
    "hobbies": [
      {
        "hobbyName": "cricket",
        "type": "outdoor"
      },
      {
        "hobbyName": "chess",
        "type": "indoor"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Here I need to search for a person.name, person.city, person.hobbies.hobbyName, person.hobbies.type.

Comment: JSON array is part of JSON definition. So it should not be a problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [array of struct](https://docs.vespa.ai/documentation/reference/search-definitions-reference.html#type:array) , something like this should get you started:

```
search person {

    document person {

        field name type string {
            indexing: summary | index
        }

        field city type string {
            indexing: summary | index
        }

        struct hobby {
            field hobbyName type string {}
            field type      type string {}
        }

        field hobbies type array<hobby> {
            indexing: summary
            struct-field hobbyName { indexing: attribute }
            struct-field type      { indexing: attribute }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The "person" is already inside a JSON object, I have modified the question, please have a look.

Comment: A subtlety of Vespa is, you can search in array of struct but not struct. It seems the record _is_ a person, and only one, so the person struct is not needed. You can rename fields to person_name, person_city and person_hobbies to make it clearer